# 127.0.0.1:9051 doesnt work after apache, mysql, php installation?

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, tor, vidalia

I have installed apache2, mysql, and php and now it doesn't let Vidalia run on localhost. I tried to change the `TCP connection (controlport)` to any other ip `192.168.0.40` and tried to change the default port `9051` to any other but that doesn't work. I thought apache is running so I used this command `sudo service apache2 stop` but that still doesn't work. So now when I type `127.0.0.1:9051` in browser it says

[image]

and if I type only type `127.0.0.1` after stopping the apapche2 service with the command mentioned above it says `unable to connect`

I am not sure what to do now.

Comment: You click on the link provided in the screenshot? Besides that: see http://superuser.com/questions/565722/how-to-config-tor-to-use-a-http-socks-proxy

Comment: This looks like Tor is actually listening on port 9050. Please add the error message you get from Vidalia to your question.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch i dont think its vidalia problem because it gives no error it connects fine and shows that its running fine but in browser i can not get traffic on `localhost:9050` it was working fine but after installing apache mysql and php this doesnt work

Comment: @Rinzwind my isp havent blocked tor network its running fine on my other system so there is problem with the service running on the localhost i guess of apache2 even if I stop the apache2 service it still doesnt let me use vidalia on browser

Answer (score 0):

Tor is neither HTTP proxy nor a web server, and under no motive it will run in port 80. The port 9051 is a control port which Vidalia uses to talk with Tor, while port 9050 is the SOCKS port where you should point your browser. I installed Apache, Tor and Vidalia and no problem arrises.

Vidalia and Tor should always communicate using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. If localhost doesn't work, is probably because is preferring ipv6 and apache has nothing to do with it. In the control port type `127.0.0.1:9051` and restart the system. Don't autostart Tor yourself, Vidalia should bring Tor up when Vidalia starts. If you start Tor before Vidalia it will fail.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by that `"Don't autostart Tor yourself, Vidalia should bring Tor up when Vidalia starts. If you start Tor before Vidalia it will fail."`
by the way i dont have tor browser i just have vidalia and i use the `127.0.0.1:9050`, socket5 on normal browser chrome or firefox

Comment: @RanaMuhammadWaqas that you should leave Vidalia to start Tor. Whenever you start Vidalia, it will start Tor but if tor is already running the startup will fail. You must make sure that no instance of Tor is running when you start Vidalia.

Comment: I rebooted my system then i checked all the processes by using this command `pgrep -l -u username` and i didnt find any tor process in that list after that I open vidalia and it connected fine but still it doesnt work on `127.0.0.1:9050` port same problem again

Answer (score 0):

I found this article https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/20906/why-cant-i-access-localhost-from-tor-browser

"
Cause localhost is local to your computer, Tor is a public network that routes your traffic around the world. The network connections Tor browser makes are not local. Tor will not attempt any connections to private networks, or localhost. The browser connection leaves your computer and goes through 3 Tor relays and finally to the destination. That exit node (which can be anywhere in the world) cannot access "localhost" on your computer since it has zero knowledge about the request, only the destination and the relay it needs to send the response back to. – drew010 -Feb 13, 2020 at 16:13"

And this one which explained why trying to re-configure tor is not recommended.

### Exclude IP addresses - where has it gone?

https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/20854/exclude-ip-addresses-where-has-it-gone/20868#20868

Bottom line for me is use firefox for localhost on a seperate computer to my tor research machine.

Hope this helps